# joomla lightbox on page load

Tags: joomla1.5

has anyone fire up lightbox on pageload using Joomla 1.5?

I want to build a plugin to fire Lightbox of an article when page load, but have no idea hw to do that

Comment: I have done that using jQuery Colorbox (Lightbox). But not with joomla's default mootools lightbox. If you want to implement the jQuery one. I can tell u.

Answer (score 1):

It is actually quite simple, when you know what you are doing.
Below is a sample code that is native to Joomla 1.5 using Mootools 1.1 and modal behavior.

If you want to use only SlimBox, then you will have to figure things out on your own. All the SlimBoxes are little different...

---

In order for us to open up a modal window we need to do 2 things.

Fist, include JavaScript libraries and stylesheets. In our case we will include `modal.js`

```
<?php
// You do know need to include mootools explicitly
// JHTML::_('behavior.modal') will include mootools library.
JHTML::_('behavior.modal');
?>
```

Second, include JavaScript to open the modal window. IF you are including JS from PHP, better use `JFactory::getDocument()->addScriptDeclaration("// JavaScript Goes Here");` to include the script into the HEAD of the document.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

// Use either domready or load event to open the modalbox
window.addEvent('domready', function(){
    var myAnchor = new Element('a', {
        'href': 'http://www.google.com',
        'class': 'myClass',
        'rel' : "{handler: 'iframe', size: {x: 800, y: 550}}"
    });
    SqueezeBox.fromElement(myAnchor);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another scenario is when you have an existing modal link on the page and you want to display the modal on page load. Use:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function(){
    SqueezeBox.fromElement(document.getElementById('modalID'));
});
```

Where link exists:

```
<a class="modal" name="modalID" id="modalID" rel="{handler: 'iframe', size: {x: 400, y:     400}}" href="index.php?option=com_mycomponent&task=mytask&tmpl=component">Link Text</a>"
```

This display the modal onload and has link to reopen modal